# Embedding Russian language edition of Ukraine map using Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, localization, embedding

Until recently, Google Maps offered a Russian language version of its Ukraine map. Every street, every place name, every POI had a Russian name tag that could be displayed if the language was set to Russian. This was very useful for areas that are mostly Russian-speaking.
However, this functionality seems to have mostly gone. If Russian is chosen, cities in Ukraine still bear Russian names but every street and most, but not all POIs are displayed in Ukrainian. This is also the case for Crimea, which has recently been annexed by Russia.

How can I embed a map of Ukraine, that uses Russian name tags? Or is this functionality gone?

Comment: Can you show the code/URL that used to work previously?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F,%20%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0,%20%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&language=ru